# How can I write data separately in many text files which contain the same fields?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a text file which contains around 9999999 lines. Here I'm pasting the few lines:

```
1874641047  Gazipur
1874646347  Jessore
1845105653  Chittagong
1845146123  Narayanganj
1845164162  Gazipur
1843908007  Jessore
```

Here 1st column contains cell phone numbers & 2nd column contains regions.

I wanted to write those data in a text files region wise, as like:

Gazipur.txt:

```
1874641047  Gazipur
1845164162  Gazipur
```

Jessore.txt:

```
1874646347  Jessore
1843908007  Jessore
```

Chittagong.txt:

```
1845105653  Chittagong
```

Narayanganj.txt:

```
1845146123  Narayanganj
```

How can I do this in Linux terminal? Is there any way to do this like `awk`, `comm`, `diff` commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{print > $2".txt"}' input-file
```

It redirects the output to a filename made from the second field.

Comment: I have executed your above shared command. Here those files are conflicting which have contains same region like for `Gazipur` & `Jessore`. Its unable to create `Jessore.txt` or `Gazipur.txt` twice.

Could you please test it by yourself and share me the command once again?

Comment: I did test it, and it worked fine for me given your sample input. It doesn't create any file twice.

Comment: Okay I'll test once again & will share the testing result with screenshot.

Comment: @Rezuan no, please don't share a screenshot. Instead, share the exact input you used, the output you would like to see and the output you actually got. Muru's solution should work, if it doesn't, there's something strange about your data.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your suggestion. @terdon

Comment: @muru Thank you for your valuable time. It is working for me now. Actually my inputted file format was wrong. There was multiple gap between two fields. Thanks man, you save my lots of time. :)